# Pls Suggest me which browser compatibility shall i provide to my Application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i don't know whether this question makes sense but still..

1. If i created an application, which browser compatibility shall i provide??
   whether to go for IE or chrome or firefox or netscape or OPERA or some other...
   even though,suppose   if i choose IE then which version to choose next?? IE6 or IE7 or some newer???
2. If my application used some newer technology like HTML5 or css3, will it be running on old browser like IE6 ???
3. today 71 percent of the population use INTERNET CAFE(Rest uses mobile,broadband and some other connection) to browse, where they have not usually upgrade their browser, so generally a common man will use the same browser.So isn't it better to create an application which will run on older versions??

thanks a lot for suggesting any ideas in advance..

Comment: Where do you get your stats from? :)

Comment: Which browsers you should support always depends on your audience and/or your clients! If your client insists on IE5.5 because that's what they're using, then you better make it IE5.5 compatible. If your audience is expected to pretty much only consist of Chrome users on OS X and there's no advantage to supporting anything else, then don't.

Comment: i was searching for multi browser constraint.., there i came across this question..

Comment: Thanks deceze u made my way easy:-)

Comment: i dont think you can find anybody using IE version less than 6 or Firefox older than 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the project you are working on and the target audience.

Are you making an intranet system and all the employees use Internet Explorer 8 then you provide support for that.

New techniques like html5 and css3 won't work in ie6, but you should provide fallback methods if your client requires your application to work in ie6.

Me personally, I only target ie8+, unless the client requires me to use older browerse

Comment: isn't this would be a solution if i explicitly define my HTML tags like h1,h2,h3,h4{
         font-size:1em; 
 font-weight:normal; 
 font-style:normal;
           }
here it will override the browser's specification for those tags and will considered the one as i specified...such that in all browser my content appears same..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But you have something called reset.css, a file that resets all default browser css.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

1)

Internet Explorer 7+
Firefox 3.6+
Chrome doesn't have versions in the conventional sense, so just "chrome".

That's what Google/Facebook/other big companies support.

2)
HTML5 features will generally *not* run on IE6, but most of them are not essential.
Look up "progressive enhancement"

3)
I don't know where you got that data from, but I'm not sure it's true.

Comment: I'm waiting for the day when we can say IE 10+ :)

Comment: for 3)-- if i create a web site, isn't it better to make it compatible with the older version or newer version??

Comment: Well, making it compatible with the older version may have bad implications. E.g. if you make it IE6 compatible, you would either have to spend twice as long making it(and thus it will end up twice as expensive), or it will not look nice in newer browsers.